# Runtime error 9 in Redim Preserve output in excel vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am not sure how to write Redim Preserve array for the following output. The output in DataTable_1 should be 4 rows and 25 columns of data. **Issue**: Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range when I reach the `Redim Preserve`. so the data is not populated.

```
For I = 0 To 3
    outputCounter = outputCounter + 1
    output(0, outputCounter) = resultsArray(1, I) 
    output(1, outputCounter) = resultsArray(2, I) 
    output(2, outputCounter) = resultsArray(3, I) 
    output(3, outputCounter) = resultsArray(4, I) 
    output(4, outputCounter) = resultsArray(5, I) 
    output(5, outputCounter) = resultsArray(6, I) 
    output(6, outputCounter) = resultsArray(7, I) 
    output(7, outputCounter) = resultsArray(8, I) 
    output(8, outputCounter) = resultsArray(9, I) 
    output(9, outputCounter) = resultsArray(10, I) 
    output(10, outputCounter) = resultsArray(11, I) 
    output(11, outputCounter) = resultsArray(12, I) 
    output(12, outputCounter) = resultsArray(13, I) 
    output(13, outputCounter) = resultsArray(14, I) 
    output(14, outputCounter) = resultsArray(15, I) 
    output(15, outputCounter) = resultsArray(16, I) 
    output(16, outputCounter) = resultsArray(17, I) 
    output(17, outputCounter) = resultsArray(18, I) 
    output(18, outputCounter) = resultsArray(19, I) 
    output(19, outputCounter) = resultsArray(20, I) 
    output(20, outputCounter) = resultsArray(21, I)
    output(21, outputCounter) = resultsArray(22, I) 
    output(22, outputCounter) = resultsArray(23, I) 
    output(23, outputCounter) = resultsArray(24, I) 
    output(24, outputCounter) = resultsArray(25, I) 
Next I
```

I have checked and the `resultsArray` is correct. I am getting a "Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range" on the `Redim Preserve` line below

```
ReDim Preserve output(0 To 24, 1 To outputCounter)
wsData.Range("A21").Value = resultsArray
wsData.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(21, 1), wsData.Cells(21 + lr, 25)), , xlYes).Name = "DataTable_1"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share the complete code from `Sub...` to `... End Sub` and a description of what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the `LBound` value if Preserve is used, only the `Ubound` can be modified.

```
ReDim Preserve output(0 To 24, 0 To outputCounter)
```

in this command only the outputCounter value is flexible.

What can be done is to create loop for the bound conversion.

```
Redim new_array(0 To 24, 1 To outputCounter)
For i = 0 To 24
    For j = 1 to outputCounter
        new_array(i, j) = output(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: How do you know lbound wasn't 1? It does not follow from the provided code.

Comment: LBound is always 0. Thanks for all the help rendered.